# ¿Como Agregar datos a una columna especifica de mi DataGridView?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Les comento, Lleno un `DataGridView` atravez de una Consulta SQL, Después leo la columna **Poliza** de mi `DataGridView` y con base a eso Busco el ultimo pago que tuvo esa póliza, Si la póliza Nunca se pago quiero Agregar **Nunca Pago** en una columna que Agregado Manualmente a mi `DataGridView` Pero no se agrega nada, solo queda en Blanco.

El Código es el Siguiente:

```
try
{
//La consulta siguiente solo es una parte de todos los datos que consulto.
   SqlDataAdapter DA2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select CONCAT(C.Nombre1,' ',C.Nombre2,' ',C.Apellido1,' ',C.Apellido2) as Nombre, DS.Poliza, from CLIENTE C, DATOSSEGURO DS Where C.NumCliente = DS.NumCliente and DS.FinVigencia BETWEEN '" + datetime1.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' and '" + datetime2.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'", MenuInicio.conexion);
   DA2.Fill(DT);
   mostrarconsulta.DataSource = DT;
//Despues de llenar la Tabla Creo una Nueva Columna
   mostrarconsulta.Columns.Add("DSP", "DSP");
//Leo el DataGridView Nuevamente para Selecciona
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in mostrarconsulta.Rows)
   {
      string PolizaPago = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Poliza"].Value);
//Consulto  la fecha del utlimo pago de la Poliza
      String ultimafecha = "Select FechaTrajo = MAX (FechaTrajo) FROM PAGOS where Poliza ='" + PolizaPago + "'";
      SqlCommand Buscafecha = new SqlCommand();
      Buscafecha.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
      Buscafecha.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      Buscafecha.CommandText = ultimafecha;
      try
      {
         Leer = Buscafecha.ExecuteReader();
         Leer.Read();
         FechaUltima = Leer["FechaTrajo"].ToString();//la ultima fecha se la coloco a una variable
         Leer.Close();
      }
      catch (SqlException ex)
      {
          Leer.Close();
      }
      if (FechaUltima == "" || FechaUltima == null)//si fecha no tiene nada o nunca pago entonces
      {
//Quiero Agregar a la columna que cree el dato que Nunca pago
         row.Cells["DSP"].Value = "Nunca Pago";
         Leer.Close();
      }
      else
      {
         Leer.Close();
      }
}
catch(SQLExeption ex)
{
}
```

Avances...

Agrego el dato a la columna que creo después de llenar el `DataGridView` de esta manera: `row.Cells[11].Value = "Nunca Pago";` ya que conozco en que columna esta.... pero No me agrega nada... sin embargo si hago la inserción en una celda que ya esta rellenada por ejemplo: `row.Cells[8].Value = "Nunca Pago";` si me agrega el **Nunca Pago** ...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hice para solucionar el problema de no poder escribir en la columna declarada fue Crear la columna desde la consulta de esta manera:

```
 Select CONCAT(C.Nombre1,' ',C.Nombre2,' ',C.Apellido1,' ',C.Apellido2) as Nombre,
 C.CentrodeTrabajo,
 .
 .
 .
 'DSP' as DSP 
 from CLIENTE C,...
 Where ...
```

Y Agrego los datos a esa columna recorriendo la tabla, leyendo la Póliza y agregandola de esta manera:
Ya que conozco el numero de la columna puedo Agregar los valores a ella de esta manera.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in mostrarconsulta.Rows)
{
 row.Cells[11].Value =Convert.ToString("NP");
}
```

Espero haber ayudado a alguien que haya tenido el mismo problema que yo.